# Improving on retrieving values for a class constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, iterator

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to set a class CONSTANT value. Since the `.each_key` method for a `hash` class seems to not return values as it makes a `map` method for `array` classes, I implemented the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  return_values = []
  CONSTANT = (1..1).map { |e|   
                HASH.each_key { |key|
                  return_values << key.to_s
                }
                return_values
              }.flatten
end
```

The above code works for me, but it is very far from being "good" code. **How can I improve that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
CONSTANT = HASH.keys.map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: @mckeed - What means the '&:' part?

Comment: It is equivalent to `HASH.keys.map {|key| key.to_s }`. It basically makes a block out of a single method's name. You can find out about the `&` notation by searching for Symbol#to_proc.

Comment: @mckeed - And if I don't want to to call the method 'to_s' how can I do?

Comment: I don't understand. Did you have a reason for calling `to_s` in your original code? It looked like you were trying to collect a list of the keys in HASH. `HASH.keys` gives you that list. The `map(&:to_s)` part makes them into strings.

Comment: @mckeed - You are right. It is just to know some more and because I discover that I really don't need to call the 'to_s' method (also for performance reason).

Comment: @mckeed - So, is it possible to not call the 'to_s' method in '&:to_s'?